# Digital Service Signature (DSS) error on compile project

Tags: java, maven

Environment:
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Temurin)(build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Temurin)(build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)
On Visual Studio Code (Versión: 1.68.1) - Docker Container (4.6.1)
Mac OS 11.6 Big Sur

Description:
I have tried to run git repo in VS cloned in docker container.
Main Repo ( https://github.com/esig/dss.git ) doesn't compile.

```
Unable to build dependency tree.
Could not resolve following dependencies: [eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-document:jar:5.10.1
Could not resolve dependencies for project eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-test:jar:5.10.1
The following artifacts could not be resolved: eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-document:jar:5.10.1, eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-token:jar:5.10.1, eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-service:jar:5.10.1, eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-utils-apache-commons:jar:5.10.1, eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-crl-parser-stream:jar:5.10.1: eu.europa.ec.joinup.sd-dss:dss-document:jar:5.10.1 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced


Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.10.0:run (default-cli) on project dss-test: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.10.0:run failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

I tried to compile demo repo ( https://github.com/esig/dss-demonstrations.git )
and doesn't compile too, pom file errors and after Fix it error on JavaFX .

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

Issue on Jira: https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/tracker/browse/DSS-2801

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [documentation](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/doc/dss-documentation.html#_integration_instructions):

```
The latest version of DSS framework has the following minimal requirements:

- Java 11 and higher (tested up to Java 17) for the build is required. For usage Java 8 is a minimum requirement;
- Maven 3.6 and higher;
- Memory and Disk: see minimal requirements for the used JVM. In general the higher available is better;
- Operating system: no specific requirements (tested on Windows and Linux).
```

Therefore, you should use at least Java 11 to build DSS project.

However, in case you need to use DSS as a dependency, then you may do it with Java 8, by adding its repository to the pom.xml of your Maven project:

```
<repositories>
    ...

    <repository>
      <id>cefdigital</id>
      <name>cefdigital</name>
      <url>https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/artifact/content/repositories/esignaturedss/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

After you will need to add the required modules as dependencies to your project (see documentation for more details about available modules). For examples of DSS integration please see [dss-demonstrations](https://github.com/esig/dss-demonstrations) project.